# Can we parallelize the email download using IMAP JavaMail API?

Tags: multithreading, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

Can I use multiple threads to download the emails using the store?
Is there any sample available anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Each open folder uses a separate connection to the server and operations on that folder are serialized by that connection so there's a limit to how much parallelism you can get with a single folder.  Some servers will allow you to open the same mailbox multiple times (using separate Folder objects), resulting in multiple connections.